# Verify that a commit message contains some string with pre-commit

Tags: git, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I would like to ensure if my commit message contains a given string using pre-commit. I tried using a pygrep based hook, but it does not handle the multiline as expected.

For example, my commit message is:

```
My commit message

Changelog: trial
```

I want to validate that the commit message contains "Changelog:".

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

with `pygrep` this is fairly easy -- but you'll need to invert the usual behaviour of `pygrep` (which is to error when *present*)

```yaml
repos:
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: needs-changelog
        name: commit message needs "Changelog:"
        language: pygrep
        entry: '^Changelog:'
        args: [--multiline, --negate]
        stages: [commit-msg]
```

this also utilizes `--multiline` such that the regex can match anywhere in the message.  `--negate` flips the usual `pygrep` behaviour

```
$ git commit -m "foo"
commit message needs "Changelog:"........................................Failed
- hook id: needs-changelog
- exit code: 1

.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG

$ git commit -m $'foo\nChangelog: whatever'
commit message needs "Changelog:"........................................Passed
[main (root-commit) 5d10868] foo Changelog: whatever
 1 file changed, 9 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .pre-commit-config.yaml
```

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit

Comment: What's the reason for not installing commit-msg stage configs during `pre-commit install`? The docs says you'd always run `pre-commit install` on repo checkout, but this wouldn't install all the specified config entries. I assume there's a valid reason for this, but doesn't this make it counter intuitive since the amazing thing about pre-commit is to easily manage a projects commit standards without complex and manual commit hook set ups?

Comment: it can, if you configure [this](https://pre-commit.com/#top_level-default_install_hook_types) -- but pre-commit can't know what ones are what stages without downloading all the tools

Answer (score 2):

Loved the answer provided by [@anthony-sottile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812183/anthony-sottile) above, and I adapted it to work for conventional commit messages!  This is my first answer contribution too!

## Solution

Create a .pre-commit-config.yaml file in your project's root directory, or just add this hook to your existing file.

```yaml
# project_root/.pre-commit-config.yaml
repos:
- repo: local
  hooks:
  - id: commit-msg
    name: conventional commit messages
    language: pygrep
    entry: '^(chore|test|feat|fix|build|docs|refactor)!?(\([a-z]+\))?: (?![A-Z])(?![a-z]+(ed|ing)\s).*$'
  args:
  - --multiline
  - --negate # fails if the entry is NOT matched
  stages:
  - commit-msg
```

Be sure to install the `commit-msg` hook as well or this pre-commit hook stage won't work.  These commands can be run in a bash terminal individually.

```bash
pip install pre-commit && \
pre-commit install --hook-type commit-msg && \
git commit -m "failing commit message" --allow-empty
```

### Adapting Guidance

Some clarification of the regex if anyone needs to repurpose this for their awesome use-case:

1. [Regex Cheat Sheet](https://download.microsoft.com/download/c/3/e/c3ef6850-d455-478a-afbe-b89e57df8569/Regular_Expressions_Cheat_Sheet.pdf) to understand the syntax
2. [Regex Simulator](https://regex101.com/) to help getting your text matched

Comment: I tried your regexp for checking conventional messages but it matches "ed" anywhere in words ... hence "editor" won't pass the check. Here is my iteration of the regex that checks only ending (and upper-case) for the first word. (And allows both 'type' and subject according to conventional commits)

```^(chore|test|feat|fix|build|docs|refactor)!?(\([a-z]+\))?: (?![A-Z])(?![a-z]+(ed|ing)\s).*$```

Comment: Bravo - nice catch and contribution!  I've added it to the answer to help other readers get the improved version.  I'm surprised no one's come across that in nearly a year of usage, haha.